# Android. AutoCompleteTextView. Как при фокусе на поле показать выпадающий список?

Tags: java, android

Имеется `AutoCompleteTextView` в него в коде заносятся значения.
Как при клике/фокусе на поле отобразить сразу список со всеми добавленными значениями?

```
AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.editFriendCode);

String[] values = new String[]{"0f020", "ca35c"};

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
textView.setAdapter(adapter);

View.OnClickListener fdcClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        view.showContextMenu(); // не работает так
    }
};

textView.setOnClickListener(fdcClick);
```

Иначе он отображает только значения если ввести 2 символа, а требуется отображать без ввода данных

Прошу помощи или подсказки другого решения

**UPD**

`setOnTouchListener` тоже не канает...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Создайте кастомный `AutoCompleteTextView`

```
public class InstantAutoComplete extends AutoCompleteTextView {

public InstantAutoComplete(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public InstantAutoComplete(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1) {
    super(arg0, arg1);
}

public InstantAutoComplete(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1, int arg2) {
    super(arg0, arg1, arg2);
}

@Override
public boolean enoughToFilter() {
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction,
        Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
    super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
    if (focused && getAdapter() != null) {
        performFiltering(getText(), 0);
    }
}
}
```

И потом в xml

```
<package.InstantAutoComplete
...
/>
```

Comment: ооо спасибо, работает

Comment: @tCode, верные ответы принято подтверждать галочкой :)

Comment: да нельзя сразу было кликнуть)

Comment: @tCode, удачи в кодинге!

Comment: а еще такой вопрос, как переопределить метод который вставляет выбранный из списка текст в поле?

Comment: Это скорее всего слушатель `OnItemClickListener` вам надо поймать момент, когда пользователь кликает на айтем списка?

Comment: Вообще хотелось поймать вставку текста из итема в поле